# Receiving an array then using a v-for to display results on multiple <select></select> A click on one option changes all other option values

Tags: arrays, vue.js, v-for

```
 <select  v-for="roles in arrayRoles">
                <option value="">Select role</option>
                <option :value="role.id" v-for="role in roles" :key="index">
                  {{ role.title }}</option>
              </select>
```

How can  I stop the simultaneous change in value when select only one option

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow! For a clearer question, I'd recommend including a bit more information in the future, such as some example data for `arrayRoles` so that answerers know more about the data structure you're working with. Also, it always helps out if you can describe a couple of alternatives/research you've done already, to help narrow down the new solutions that answerers might propose.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing a `:key` on the outer `v-for`, and even in the inner `v-for` you're missing the declaration of `index`.

I made some assumptions about the contents of `arrayRoles` and found the following template to work:

```
    <select v-for="(roles, index) in arrayRoles" :key="index">
        <option value="">Select role</option>
        <option v-for="(role, i) in roles" :key="i" :value="role.id">
            {{ role.title }}
        </option>
    </select>
```

A sample `arrayRoles` I used for testing:

```
        [
            [
                { id: 1, title: 'one' },
                { id: 2, title: 'two' },
                { id: 3, title: 'three' }
            ],
            [
                { id: 4, title: 'four' },
                { id: 5, title: 'five' },
                { id: 6, title: 'six' }
            ],
            [
                { id: 1, title: 'one' },
                { id: 2, title: 'two' },
                { id: 3, title: 'three' }
            ]
        ]
```

Comment: Thank you @RNanoware for the quick reply your solution is working. ill give more info of my questions